# getting Invariant Violation in React native. Implementing Splashscreen

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I have been having some difficulty implementing splashscreen this Hence i wanted to show this maybe someone would be of help.

https://postimg.cc/ftf0psfy

I am getting that Error. But at this point i really don't know where I am making the mistake here, My Code looks like this

**App.js**

```
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator
 } from 'react-navigation';

 import Splashscreen from './components/Splashscreen';
 import Login from './components/Login'

 const HomeNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Splash: Splashscreen,
  Home: Login,
 });   
 const RouteConfigs = {
  SplashScreen: {
  screen: Splashscreen
 },
 Home: {
  screen: Login
 }
};

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
 RouteConfigs,
 {
  initialRouteName: "SplashScreen"
 }
);
```

Now My splashscreen Code looks like this

**Splashscreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image , ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, Modal } from 'react-native';

export default class Splashscreen extends Component{

    componentDidMount()
    {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')  
        }, 4000);
    }

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
            source={{uri: 'http://peopleweb.freeasphost.net/d4b0e7d1-6c0e-4e48-a4cb-0f1c26af81fe_200x200.png'}}
         style={styles.logo} />
        </View>
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent :"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    logo:{
    width:150,
    height:150
},
});
```

And the Login page which would be redirected much Later on Looks like this

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View , TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component{

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        placeholder = "Username"
        style={styles.input}
        />

        <TextInput
        placeholder = "Password"
        style={styles.input}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.login}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Login </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent :"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    input:{
        width:200,
        margin:10
    },

    button:{
        width:200,
        padding:10,
        backgroundColor:'#009999',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    loginbtn:{
        color:'#ffff'
    }
});
```

Plss i do need guides as to what I am doing. What could the error be ? I am new to this

Comment: Can you include you error as text in your question? I can't see the image.

Comment: Invariant Violation Element Type is invalid